# Swift random point on screen for SKNode

Tags: swift, sknode, skview

I am trying to generate a random point on the screen to create an SKSpriteNode:

```
let px : CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
let py : CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
let screenSize : CGRect = self.frame
let location = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width*px,y: screenSize.height*py)
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BlackCircle.png")
```

Although this generates points correctly within the frame, sometimes the node itself is not created because the location in the frame does not correctly translate to a location within the GameScene. I tested positions using:

```
print(touch.locationInNode(self))
print(touch.locationInView(self.view))
```

I know there should be some offset for the x and y coordinates, but I cannot figure them out. Am I using the wrong CGRect? I tried using:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.frame
```

and

```
view!.frame
```

as screenSize instead, but I had the same problem. What CGRect should I use?

Comment: You can use CGRectGetMaxX or CGRectGetMaxY and use an arc4random_uniform for them

Comment: I can find the dimensions of the CGRect without a problem, but I cannot seem to find the correct CGRect to measure or how to finds it relative position to the screen.